# How get cell value from jquery datatable

Tags: jquery, datatable

I have a datatable with datas, when I click above one data i would like be able to get this value and do something.

i've tried with "fnGetData" function but it doesn't work.

I have this code :

```
    cclients.otable=$('#turlexceptions').dataTable({
        'bDestroy': true,
        'bAutoWidth': false,
        'sDom': "<'row'<'span5'><'dtrt'>r>t<'row'<'span5'><'dtrt'>>",
        'sScrollY': '200px',
        'bPaginate': false,
        'bScrollCollapse': true,
        "aaData": cclients.urlexceptions($('#icle_s_urlexcept').val()),
        'aoColumnDefs': [
            {'aTargets':[0],'sTitle':'Webs No Registradas'},
            {'aTargets':[1],'sName':'remove','sTitle':'','sWidth':'15px','mDataProp':null,'bSearchable':false,'bSortable':false,'sClass':'tdactions','sDefaultContent':'<a href="javascript:cclients.removeurlexception('+ $(this).text()+')" class="eremove label label-important" title="Remove">x</a>'}
         ]
    });
```

thanks.

Comment: This value? Do you mean TD text?

Comment: i've written $(this).text() after do few test.
I need get the value in colunm [0] from cell selected

Answer (score 0):

First initialize data table as follows:

```
var userTable =$('#turlexceptions').dataTable({
        'bDestroy': true,
        'bAutoWidth': false,
        'sDom': "<'row'<'span5'><'dtrt'>r>t<'row'<'span5'><'dtrt'>>",
        'sScrollY': '200px',
        'bPaginate': false,
        'bScrollCollapse': true,
        "aaData": cclients.urlexceptions($('#icle_s_urlexcept').val()),
        'aoColumnDefs': [
            {'aTargets':[0],'sTitle':'Webs No Registradas'},
            {'aTargets':[1],'sName':'remove','sTitle':'','sWidth':'15px','mDataProp':null,'bSearchable':false,'bSortable':false,'sClass':'tdactions','sDefaultContent':'<a href="javascript:cclients.removeurlexception('+ $(this).text()+')" class="eremove label label-important" title="Remove">x</a>'}
         ]
    }); 



--------------------

For get the selected data:

var position =  userTable .fnGetPosition( this );
if(position !=null){

    var selectedData = userTable .fnGetData( position );
    alert("SELECTED DATA::"+selectedData); 

}
```

Comment: it doesn't work
when I try to  read var position =  userTable .fnGetPosition( this );
I get an error

Comment: where u added this code. when u need selected data while clicking any element?

Comment: I've only added : var userTable...for the datatable code and the second part of code (var position.....) in a function (javascript:cclients.removeurlexception) => this is my href in colunm remove

Comment: hi, pls post the code where u have var position code.